# preg_replace works from command line but not from browser?

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

I have a sql file which has the comments inside it.

```
/*
IMP : Only use C-Style comments only

Every ID field should have this convention "tableName_id" , 
where tableName is the name of table, whom this id refers

*/

/*
It stores the system wide information 
we need at the time of updates or debugging.
*/
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__payplans_support` (
  `support_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key`           VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `value`         TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`support_id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idx_key` (`key` ASC) 
)
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 ; 


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `#__payplans_config` (  
  `config_id`   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
/*name of tab*/
  `title`       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `key`     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `config`      TEXT NULL ,
  `componentname` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
/* xml and default ini path */
  `path` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`config_id`) ,
  INDEX `idx_key` (`key` ASC)
)
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 ;
```

The code below filters the comment from above sql.

```
$sql = file_get_content(from above file);
$var =  preg_replace("!/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/!s","",$sql); // EDIT
```

PROBLEM :

It is working perfectly in Linux (Command Line and from browser).

But It in not working on windows from Browser, but working with Windows command line the browser shows `The connection was reset...`

Please give me any solution.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the problem you're having, but you should have single quotes around the regex in php.  With double quotes, \r and \n get converted into control characters by the string parser.

Comment: thanks for the advice. But it didn't do anything.

Comment: I suspect some weird character might be the reason. How about var_export(preg_replace(....)) instead of echo, does it work?

Comment: @Alexey : actually I am assigning this to a variable. So it does not matter here for echo or var_export.

Comment: Why do you want to strip off the comments? Doesn't the SQL execute with them? Try using the "--" comments instead of /* ... */ ones if you're unable to execute the SQL with inline comments.

Comment: @Adarsh : I want to get each query and then execute it.

Comment: @Guarav - Just provide the solution and accept the answer :)

Comment: @Tim : But I didn't get any solution, I just remove the comments from my sql file. Now what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get any correct solution here. So I just removed the comments from sql file.